# Plot multiple lines from multiple dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these piece of code to draw two line charts ( confirmed cases and death cases)
How to show both curves in one chart with two dataframes (two ggplots)?
Is it even possible or do I need to merge my two dataframes ( conf_data, dead_data ) into  one data_frame ?

```
ggplot(conf_data, aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
        geom_line(colour = "blue", size =1.1, aes(date, confirmed)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)

  ...

      ggplot(dead_data, aes(x = date, y = deaths)) +
        geom_line(colour = "red", size =1.1, aes(date, deaths)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

Here is my current working example with just one chart
http://webcovid19.online/

Comment: It’s possible — but why not join the data? 9 out of 10 times that’s what you want to do.

Comment: yes, you have right, join is the best option ( also for performance, I hope) , but  as you advised me also two dataframes option is working, let me check... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(conf_data, aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
        geom_line(colour = "blue", size =1.1, aes(date, confirmed)) +
        geom_line(colour = "red", size =1.1, aes(date, deaths)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass custom data to a geometry via the `data` argument:

```
ggplot(conf_data, aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
    geom_line(color = "blue", size = 1.1, aes(date, confirmed)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    geom_line(color = "red", size = 1.1, aes(date, deaths), data = dead_data)
```

However, most of the time it’s more convenient to merge the data prior to plotting — if for no other reason, then because it allows you to create a proper legend and provide custom colour scales etc.:

```
bind_rows(
    transmute(conf_data, number = confirmed, type = 'confirmed'),
    transmute(death_data, number = deaths, type = 'deaths')
) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = number, color = type, group = type)) +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Hi Rudolph, I already use the 2nd option ( join dataframes ..), however is there some option to filter in multi charts ( countries in my case) to show only top 10 lines, to speed up ggplot ?  Or I have to do it my self, filter dataframes before ggplot ?  ( I did it already this way, see my site.)

Comment: @Andrew Unfortunately you have to do the filtering yourself, I’m not aware of an option inside ‘ggplot2’ to do the filtering.